# .htaccess RewriteRule Automatically URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Well i got this code at my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule page/(.*) ?page=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?search=$1
RewriteRule post/(.*) post.php?id_post=$1
```

And it works but i need to change manually the url.

And i have alots of pages to change it.

Theres any other way to put code at .htaccess and make the browser gets the proper url automatically?

Example:

http://example.com/post.php?id_post=1

http://example.com/post/1

Comment: how i do that? could you tell me please. thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2):

```
# Redirect old Page URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/?page=pagename
# New URL format: http://example.com/page/pagename
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old Search URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/search.php?search=keyword
# New URL format: http://example.com/search/keyword
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} search.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old Post URLs to new URLs
# Old URL format: http://example.com/post.php?id_post=1
# New URL format: http://example.com/post/1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_post=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post/%1? [R=301,L]

# ** Any requests with an old URL should have been processed before this comment,
# ** and any requests with a new URL should only be processed by these rules:

# Support new SEO-friendly URLs
RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?search=$1
RewriteRule post/(.*) post.php?id_post=$1
```

Comment: i guess it worked the url changed but appears this error at my chrome ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS so i guess something is wrong could u help please thanks ;D

Comment: i delete everything on my htaccess and test it again and still does that problem

Comment: That error suggests the redirects are stuck in a loop. I've modified the code in my answer, third line from bottom where it had `?page=$1` I have changed this to `index.php?page=$1`, see if this helps. Also I've added a comment in the middle to help explain where the processing is divided between old and new URLs. Also worth noting you may need to close your browser or flush its cache as it may be remembering previous redirect headers rather than observing your new rules.